# Why Ioc-Containers in Objective-C is not a popular approach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I was wondering, why in Objective-C [Ioc-Containers](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) are so unpopular ?
I found only few frameworks and just couple articles about it.

However, Ioc-Containers are extremely popular in other languages like C#, Java, etc.

What is the reason ?
Am I suppose to use something else in Objective-C for Dependency Injections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same feelings but all my iOS projects use [Typhoon framework](http://typhoonframework.org/) as DI framework. (There're a lot good reasons [why Typhoon is a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14236154/656430))

[A blog in Objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-15/dependency-injection.html) mentioned about swizzling technique that dynamically replacing one method with another. However The author still like DI more as "**it makes dependencies explicit**" (that's why I like DI too).

As typhoon mentioned in its FAQ: categories, method swizzling, duck-typing, class clusters, associative references in categories, none of these are replacement of DI. (But [some](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149908) [argues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065904/656430).)

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394899/656430) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code) [lots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Advantages) [of](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) [advantages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-containers) of DI / IOC.

I guess the main reason not popular for objective-c community is: there's no auto wiring feature which requires to code custom component assemblies. Or somehow [it's hard to sell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149792/dependency-injection-how-to-sell-it).